# Can I ask for a blog review at PSE?

Tags: discussion, blog

I've decided to start writing a blog about programming and I'd like to ask for reviews of my style of writing. If it's too slow, too fast, if it's confusing, anything. Is it appropriate to make this question at PSE or is there a board that is more appropriate? Thanks in advance!

Cheers

Comment: You can ask for feedback in Programmers' chat.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That would not be an appropriate post for PSE. If nothing else, it'd be entirely localized to your situation and we're programming experts, not writing experts.

You can try [Writing Stack Exchange](http://writers.stackexchange.com). From their [FAQ](https://writers.stackexchange.com/faq), it looks like they accept some kinds of review questions. I suggest asking on their meta to double-check and be sure.

Comment: I did think about the writing stack exchange board, but I think it would be a pretty hard read (if not boring) for someone outside programming. Thanks for the kind reply though!

Comment: If you're not looking for a content review and want a writing style assessment instead, I think they're the best place to go to.

Answer (score 4):

Not a good question for P.SE.  You could always try to find some volunteers in chat, just try not to be to spammy about it.